# I need formula in column name "FEBRUARY"

Tags: excel-formula

I have a set of data as below.

**SHEET 1**

```
                +------+-------+
                |    JANUARY   |
                +------+-------+
+----+----------+------+-------+
| ID | NAME     |COUNT | PRICE |
+----+----------+------+-------+
| 1  |  ALFRED  |  11  |  150  |
| 2  |  ARIS    |  22  |  120  |
| 3  |  JOHN    |  33  |  170  |
| 4  |  CHRIS   |  22  |  190  |
| 5  |  JOE     |  55  |  120  |
| 6  |  ACE     |  11  |  200  |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

**SHEET2**

```
+----+----------+------+-------+
| ID | NAME     |COUNT | PRICE |
+----+----------+------+-------+
| 1  |  CHRIS   |  13  |  123  |
| 2  |  ACE     |  26  |  165  |
| 3  |  JOE     |  39  |  178  |
| 4  |  ALFRED  |  21  |  198  |
| 5  |  JOHN    |  58  |  112  |
| 6  |  ARIS    |  11  |  200  |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

The RESULT should look like this in sheet1 :

```
                +------+-------++------+-------+
                |    JANUARY   |   FEBRUARY    |
                +------+-------++------+-------+
+----+----------+------+-------++-------+-------+
| ID | NAME     |COUNT | PRICE || COUNT | PRICE |
+----+----------+------+-------++-------+-------+
| 1  |  ALFRED  |  11  |  150  ||  21   |  198  |       
| 2  |  ARIS    |  22  |  120  ||  11   |  200  |       
| 3  |  JOHN    |  33  |  170  ||  58   |  112  |       
| 4  |  CHRIS   |  22  |  190  ||  13   |  123  |       
| 5  |  JOE     |  55  |  120  ||  39   |  178  |       
| 6  |  ACE     |  11  |  200  ||  26   |  165  |         
+----+----------+------+-------++-------+-------+
```

I need formula in column name "FEBRUARY". this formula will find its match in sheet 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT T2.ID_ENTRY, T1.TAG, T1.TAG2, T2.Name, T2.LastName, T2.Age, T2.Tel
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T2.ID_ENTRY, T1.TAG, T1.TAG2, T2.Name, T2.LastName, T2.Age, T2.Tel
HAVING Count(T2.ID_ENTRY) > 1
```

Comment: Column 'Table2.ID_ENTRY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  - got this error

Comment: Have you checked that it's in the group by - like it's shown in my answer above? I did have a minor syntax error - now fixed.

Comment: thanks i got it. one more question it is possible to count 2 fields for example count(T2.Name & T2.LastName)

Comment: Not exactly, you can use COUNT(T2.Name) as T2NameCount, COUNT(T2.LastName) as T2LastNameCount, etc..

Answer (score 1):

**BUILD SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table table1(
    id int,
    id_entry varchar(10),
    tag int,
    tag2 int
)
create table table2(
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
    lastname varchar(50),
    age int,
    tel int
)
insert into table1
select 1, 'A1', 11, 12 union all
select 2, 'C2', 22, 13 union all
select 3, 'S5', 33, 14 union all
select 4, 'C2', 22, 13 union all
select 5, 'B6', 55, 16 union all
select 6, 'A1', 11, 12

insert into table2
select 1, 'ALFRED', 'DAVE', 21, 555 union all
select 2, 'FRED', 'SMITH', 22, 666 union all
select 3, 'MANNY', 'PAC', 23, 777 union all
select 4, 'FRED', 'DAVE', 22, 666 union all
select 5, 'JOHN', 'SMITH', 25, 999 union all
select 6, 'ALFRED', 'DAVE', 21, 555
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;with cte as(
    select
        t1.id_entry,
        t1.tag,
        t1.tag2,
        t2.name,
        t2.lastname,
        t2.age,
        t2.tel,
        cc = count(*) over(partition by t1.id_entry),
        rn = row_number() over(partition by t1.id_entry order by t2.lastname desc)
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
        on t2.id = t1.id
)
select
    id_entry,
    tag,
    tag2,
    name,
    lastname,
    age,
    tel
from cte
where 
    cc > 1
    and rn = 1
```

**DROP SAMPLE DATA**

```
drop table table1
drop table table2
```